# jquery script not working after postback even with pageLoad

Tags: jquery, asp.net-2.0, postback

I've got some trouble with `jQuery` script on my Asp.net page. During first load it works well, after postback it does not. Initially I thought that it is because script is not load again, but alert told me that script runs as I use function `pageLoad()` instead of `$(document).ready(function()`.
In script I just read value from one text area and set the length value to next text input. I am putting script into page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/smsanywhere.js"></script>
```

I tried to place directly into page, but there is no difference I guess.

The script is shown below.

```js
    function pageLoad()
    {
       alert('pageLoad is there');
       var textBox  = "textarea[id*='txtMessage']";
       var counterBox  = "input[id*='txtCharLeft']";

       $(textBox).keydown(function(){ 
          alert(this);
          var length = 70 - $(this).val().length;
          $(counterBox).val(length);
          $(counterBox).attr("style",function(){
             return "width:30px;" + (length < 0 ? "background-color:Red;" : "");
         });
       });
    }
```

I don't use any `ajax` at this page, its just master page , content page and `jQuery`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem....as I add reference to jquery  like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl myJs = new HtmlGenericControl();
myJs.TagName = "script";
myJs.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
myJs.Attributes.Add("language", "javascript"); //don't need it usually but for cross browser.
myJs.Attributes.Add("src", ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"));
Page.Header.Controls.Add(myJs);
```

But I placed inside if (!IsPostBack){ ... } so I was ....solution is only to remove it from this condition and run it each time...uff.

So mystery sorted out...